# How to split Webform in multi menus/tabs?

Tags: webforms

Is it possible to split my webform into several menus/tab?

Note: aim is not to obtain a multi step webform but a webform with several sections reachable easily by selecting a tab.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [Webform Navigation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webformnavigation) module which allows you to let users navigate back and forth between steps of a multi-step form via the progress bar. How you design these steps in the progress bar is up to you. If you want them look like **tabs**, style the steps to look like tabs. That's all.

> The goal of this module is to provide the ability to navigate forward
> and backward through a web form using the Webform Progress tracker
> (aka wizard progress bar) supplied by the webform module on multi-page
> web forms. It also allows for the ability to bypass validation when
> the user presses the "next" button as they navigate through the form.

Alternatively use collapsible fieldsets to contain sections of your webform.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have

- one `radios` element set to display as buttons (type radio, options display: buttons horizontal; these are your tabs)
- each tabpanel a `fieldset` or `container`
- each tabpanel a condition to only show if the right tab is selected in the radios element (make sure not to 'clear values when hidden')
- then css the buttons into tabs